# Laravel relations

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I am creating a basic forum just so I have something meaningful to do while learning Laravel.
So just like every forum is organized, on the main page i would like to have a list of categories and their subcategories, a total count of posts in every subcategory while also a link to latest post

So relationship is nested hasMany:

```
Category -> has Subcategories -> has Threads -> has Posts.
```

In controller method I have

```
$cat = Category::with('subcategory')->get();
return View::make('forum.index', compact('cat'));
```

and this works for basic list of categories and subcategories but I can't figure out the rest.
This sure doesnt work

```
Category::with('subcategory')->with('threads')->with('posts')->get();
```

since relation between them is not set. Looking at Laravel docs, there is hasManyThrough relation. Is that a solution?

```
class Category extends Eloquent {

    public function subcategory()       {
        return $this->hasMany('Subcategory');
    }

    public function posts()     { // not sure about this cause it doesnt work
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Post', 'Thread');
    }
}
```

And on top of that how do I get posts->count() for every subcategory? Is it possible to have it split? Chaining could get complicated..

**EDIT**
Table columns are

Categories

```
   id | title
```

Subcategory

```
   id | title | category_id
```

Threads

```
   id | title | subcategory_id | user_id
```

Posts

```
   id | title | body | thread_id | user_id
```

**EDIT 2**
What would be the code for grabing only latest post? This doesnt work

```
$data =  Category::with('subcategories.threads')->with(array('posts' => function($query)
{
    $query->take(1);

}))->get();
```

Comment: Provide field names used in your tables.

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha I have edit my post. I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210628/laravel-relationships

See my answer, could be helpful ;)

Answer (score 3):

You have setup only one relation that works and that is:

```
class Category extends Eloquent {

    public function subcategory()       {
        return $this->hasMany('Subcategory');
    }
}
```

Declare other relationships in other models:

```
class Subcategory extends Eloquent {

    public function threads()       {
        return $this->hasMany('Thread');
    }
}

class Thread extends Eloquent {

    public function posts()       {
        return $this->hasMany('Post');
    }
}
```

Once you have declared relationships then you may use:

```
$categories = Category::with('subcategory.threads.posts')->get();
```

Since the one `Category` has many `subcategories` so use the plural name for `subcategories` instead of `subcategory` in your `Category` model, so for example, you may use:

```
class Category extends Eloquent {

    public function subcategories()       {
        return $this->hasMany('Subcategory');
    }
}
```

Then also:

```
$categories = Category::with('subcategories.threads.posts')->get();
```

All relationships will be retrieved as nested object collections. For example:

```
$categories->subcategories; // Will be a collection of Subcategory models
$categories->subcategories->threads // Will be a collection of Thread models
$categories->subcategories->threads->posts // Will be a collection of Post models
```

You may declare a `hasManyThrough` relationship between `Subcategory` and `Post` using something like this:

```
class Subcategory extends Eloquent {

    public function threads() {
        return $this->hasMany('Thread');
    }

    public function posts() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Post', 'Thread');
    }
}
```

Also, you may build a relationship between `Category` and `Thread` through `Subcategory`.

Comment: I had those relations set in models, but chaining with arrows didnt work, while your chaining with dots works perfectly. I am only worried about fetching everything, because i dont really want to grab all threads and posts, i just need to count them.  But how would i load only latest post? I have edited my question. I was trying to expand your answer with example from laravel docs... thank you  for your time :)

Comment: Use `$yourModel->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(1)`

Comment: I tried that but the error is "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::posts()". I guess i need a method 'posts' in Category model? but what to return there?

Answer (score 1):

I have 
QuestionCategory and `Questions['category_id']` and `ItemsOfQuestion['question_id']`
This Code has Work for my I hope that is useful for you

```
$categories=ExamCategory::with(['question' => function ($query) use($exam){$query->where('exam_id','=',$exam->id)->with('Items');}])->get();
```