# how to retrieve eloquent model, where a field in a related model equals "xx"?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model, eloquent

I have a two models "user" and "user_groups"

there is a relation between the two models like so:

```
public function usergroup()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\user_group','id','group_id');
}
```

I can get all users of the group "drivers" using this method.

```
 $driversx = User::where('group_id',3)->get();
```

but I wanna get these users using the "group_name" field in the "user_groups" model.

how can I achieve that?

Comment: Add a belongs to relation in your user_groups model

Comment: can you please place a clear example. thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method:

```
User::whereHas('usergroup', function ($q) {
    $q->where('group_name', 'drivers');
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally we used like this way

```
  public function Menus(){

     return $this->hasOne('App\Models\MainMenu', 'id', 'menu_id');
}
```

Controller:

```
$menu_listing=MenuListing::with('Menus')->get();
```

But if you want to use with group_name go for [belongs to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210628/laravel-relationships)

Comment: I wish to use group_name , could you please make a clear example for it?

Answer (score 0):

For your belongsTo relationship :

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User','id','group_id');
}
```

and then :

```
$users = UserGroup::where('group_name', 'drivers')->first()->users
```

the name of your model may be not UserGroup :)