# Laravel 5.2 How to access Foreign Key in View

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i know this question already asked before. But i still can't understand how it works, so i ask again. The title explain my question everything.

I have 2 tables, `products` and `product_types`

in `products`

```
id
name
type_id
```

in `product_types`

```
id
type_name
```

Here's my `Product` Model

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function productType() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\ProductType', 'type_id');
    }
}
```

Here's my `ProductType` Model

```
class ProductType extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'product_types';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function product() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

Here's my Controller for my view

```
public function viewManageProduct() {
    $products = Product::all();
    $productTypes = ProductType::all();
    return view('manages.products')->with(['products' => $products]);
}
```

my View

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $product->productType->type_name }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
@endforeach
```

I don't know how to access the `type_name` . Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

Comment: You Cant get Like this " $product->productType->type_name " Because You dont have a field like "productType" in your product table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210628/laravel-relationships)

Comment: i'm thinking about using DB::select() is that okay? or there is simple way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, i already find the answer. Thanks for your reply anyway.

Here's my code:

`products` table migration

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->integer('mediumPrice');
    $table->integer('largePrice');
    $table->string('image');
    $table->string('product_type_id')->references('product_type_id')->on('product_types');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

`product_types` table migration

```
Schema::create('product_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('product_type_id');
    $table->string('product_type_name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

`Product` model

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function product_type() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\ProductType', 'product_type_id', 'product_type_id');
    }
}
```

`ProductType` model

```
class ProductType extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'product_types';
    protected $primaryKey = 'product_type_id';

    public function product_type() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'product_type_id', 'product_type_id');
    }
}
```

`view` controller

```
public function view() {
    $products = Product::all();
    return view('manages.products')->with(['products' => $products]);
}
```

And last my HTML View

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $product->product_type['product_type_name'] }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
@endforeach
```

Once again, thank you for your reply. That's really a big help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Simplest Way 
In Your Controller

```
$products = Product::all();
$productTypes = ProductType::all();

$data['products'] = $products;
$data['productTypes'] = $productTypes;
return view('manages.products',$data);
```

In Your View Page you can get like this
$products and $productTypes. In **Your View Page**

```
    @foreach ($products as $product)
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $productTypes->type_name }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
@endforeach
```

Hopes Its Work

Answer (score 0):

There is no foreign key on `product_types` table for one-to-one relationship. So create a foreign key column in the `product_types` table.

```
+============+          +===================+
|  Products  |          |   ProductTypes    |
+============+          +===================+
|     id     |  ---|    |        id         |
+------------+     |    +-------------------+
|    name    |     |--> |   <foreign_key>   |
+------------+          +-------------------+
|   type_id  |          |      type_name    |
+------------+          +-------------------+
```

Your `hasOne` relationship would be

```
public function productType() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\ProductType', 'foreign_key');
}
```

and `hasMany` relationship would be

```
public function product() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'type_id');
}
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: my `type_id` on `products` is the foreign key

Comment: `type_id` is the foreign key of `product_types` as you have one to many relationship from Product Types to Products but there is no one to one relationship foreign key from `product` to `product_types`

Answer (score 0):

In your Product model change the function like this,

```
public function productType() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ProductType', 'type_id');
}
```

Hope this will work.